# Running Vite-React: Trouble with 'npm run dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

When I try to run the code, I get the following message.

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
     ^

      Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Web-Development\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I usually use `npm run dev` to run it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. The issue was with the folder name I used, which included '&'. It caused some problems.